# VBA look down column in Excel and find value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a value by looking down column E in another workbook.

The value is hidden in amongst text in a cell.

Cell Example:

This Is Some Text `My Value` This is some text

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Find()
Dim FoundRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks("Supplier Contacts.xlsx")
If wb Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("G:\QUALITY ASSURANCE\06_SUPPLIER INFORMATION\Supplier Contacts.xlsx")
End If

With wb.Worksheets("Listed Supplier")

Set rng = .Columns("E:E")
Do While rng.Value <> Empty
If InStr(rng.Value, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B3").Value) = 0 Then
Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
rng.Select

Else

MsgBox "I contain a % symbol!"
End If
Loop

End With
End Sub
```

Nothing seems to happen, and excel crashes.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: do not use `Empty` use `""` in your do. and I believe you have your InStr criteria backwards.

Comment: You may want to look into Find() and/or Application.WorksheetFunction.Match.  They both will be quicker than looping.

Comment: @ScottCraner i'm affraid i do not know how to do this. I'm brand new to VBA. Are you able to please show me?

Comment: @ScottCraner i tried "", no change

Comment: `Set rng = .Columns("E1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your issues is that your `rng` variable is referring to an entire column, and you are then asking the code to take the value.

After your `With` statement, try this code;

```
For Each rng in wb.Range("E:E")
    If IsEmpty(rng.value) = False Then
      If InStr(String1:=rng.Value, String2:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B3").Value) <> 0 Then
         MsgBox "I contain a % symbol!"
      End If
   End If
Next rng
```

The purpose of the `String1:=` and `String2:=` is to specify that these are the conditions you are referring to as the first condition for `InStr` is `Start:=`